`tasks.json` `dependsOn` doesn't keep shell state after successful execution
I have a tasks.json in my VSCode that doesn't preserve the command-line environment from the dependsOn task that has been successfully executed:
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Desktop Development Debug",
      "cargo": {
        "args": [
          "build",
          "--manifest-path=./frontend/app/src-tauri/Cargo.toml",
          "--no-default-features"
        ]
      },
      // task for the `beforeDevCommand` if used, must be configured in `.vscode/tasks.json`
      "preLaunchTask": "ui:dev"
    },

tasks.json:
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "desktop:setup",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "nvm",
      "args": [
        "use",
      ],
      "isBackground": true,
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend/app"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "ui:dev",
      "type": "npm",
      "isBackground": true,
      "script": "next-dev",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend/app"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "desktop:setup"
      ]
    },

Errors:
 *  Executing task: nvm use 

Found '/path-to-project/frontend/app/.nvmrc' with version <v20.14.0>
Now using node v20.14.0 (npm v10.7.0)
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: npm run next-dev 


> app@0.3.4 next-dev
> next dev -p 1420

You are using Node.js 16.20.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.

 *  The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l', '-i', '-c', 'npm run next-dev'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

Any clue?

This was raised as a feature-request in tasks.json support to reuse the same shell #168947, but it didn't receive enough community support in time to get added to the backlog. You could try raising the feature-request again. As shown in the issue ticket, depending on context (Ex. task type, whether the tasks share other properties, etc.), you can work around this by writing a single shell task and using shell mechanisms to do multiple commands on one commandline. Ex. bash &&.
Also related:

If the environment variable value is statically known and applicable to all your tasks, you can just define it in an options.env property at the top level as shown in Environment variables not persisted across task chains #38793.
Use a shared, persistent environment for tasks #44152.
For preLaunchTask in launch.json, see
Can preLaunchTask and launch start within the same terminal in VSCode?.

